# Getting a Windows 10 VirtualBox VM to fully utilize the Retina display’s resolution on a macOS host

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox

I am running Windows 10 in VirtualBox on my Retina display MacBook Pro.

The maximum resolution I can set in the guest OS is 1920 x 1440, but I would like to take advantage of the Retina display’s 2560x1400 display.

I have been scouring the internet to no avail, how do I do this?

Comment: Search for `HiDPI` and `DPI` (meaning high dots-per-inch count of [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)) and `PPI` (pixels per inch) as the technical terms used for [*Retina Display*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_Display) on non-Apple platforms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the VirtualBox Manager, navigate to the desired machines settings > Display > HiDPI Support.

Check `Use Unscaled HiDPI Output`.

In the virtual machine, select your desired resolution.

Comment: What should I do if there is no "Use Unscaled HiDPI Output" option in the Display section of settings? I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Comment: Same here, this shit is weak.

Comment: Try to set 200% if there isn't HiDPI setting.

Comment: I tried then but then it only shows me like the top left 1/4 of the screen and doesn't scale properly.

Answer (score 19):

As of VirtualBox v6 the settings have changed. You can now use the new screen scaling functionality.

For the selected machine: `Settings -> Display -> Screen -> Scale Factor`, and use the slider/text field to set the desired screen scaling percentage.

Comment: That's upsampling, not HiDPI scaling.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the Oracle VM Guest Additions installed. Once I installed the latest according to the version of the VirtualBox I installed on my host OS everything worked like a charm.

On your Windows 10 Virtual Machine, at the lower right-corner of the screen you'll see a `^`. Click on it, and you'll see the VirtualBox Icon Running. If you see that but you still can get full resolution changes are you have the incorrect version installed.

Open up `Windows File Explorer`, click on the CD Drive containing the `Virtual Machine Addons` and install it.

Alternatively you can also hover your mouse towards the top of the screen to expose the VirtualMachine Menu, Select `Devices` and select `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`.